# Which model should be used for (event in %, time) prediciton. The distribution is not linear

Tags: statistics, artificial-intelligence, linear-regression, prediction

I have a some measurements for the parking occupancy by the whole day. It means in the night the parking is fully occupied. Around noon the occupancy is not high.

If I illustrate it on X, Y diagram, then it looks something like a parabola (-x^2)
X-axis is the time from midnight to 11:59 pm
Y-axis Free parking spaces in %

Which model would be more suitable to make predictions? lineare regression? rather it should be non lineare regression, right? or should I take another model?

Comment: Would you please post the data or a scatterplot?

Comment: I have to prepare the scatterplot, I'll add it after I have done it

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/Thj8Tv5/scatterplot.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be distinct groups of data, here crudely drawn by hand. Two early morning groups, two evening groups, and a single mid-day group. My suggestion is to break the data into different models depending on the time of day: one for the early hours, one for the middle of the day, and one for the evening hours. If you have any way to distinguish the two morning and two evening groups the modeling would be quite improved - for example they might be people wo pay daily versus monthly.

[image]

Comment: Philips I have a question about normalization. My feature vectors are: time (from 0 to 23),  traffic_density (from 0 : low to 3 : very high), facility (like toilet, motorwayRestaurant, picnicFacilities....) should I normalizate the features? because I read, If there are inherent importance differences between features, it’s generally not a good idea to do standardization. E.g. time is very important and picnicFacilities not really ;) btw. i'm using SVR with RBF kernel. I have no idea how can I do it...

Comment: I suggest asking this on the statistics "sister site" at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as it is generally more statistics oriented than Stack Overflow. You should describe the basic problem to be solved, the nature of the data, and preferred statistics package or programming language. Based on what I have observed, the answers and advice that you will find there should be excellent.